# Proving a $(x,S)$-fan always exists within a $k$-connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I wish to show that a graph is $k$-connected if and only if $|V(G)| > k$ and for every $v\in V(G)$ and $S \subseteq V(G) \setminus \{v\}$ with $|S| \geq k$ there is a $(v,S)$-fan of $k$-paths.

---

I wish to show the $\implies$ direction first.

Let $G$ be a $k$-connected graph $x \in V(G)$, and let $S = V(G)\setminus \{x\}$ be a vertex set with at least $k$ elements. We wish to show that $G$ contains a $(x,S)$-fan with cardinality $k$. Since $G$ is $k$-connected, then there are $k$ pairwise disjoint paths for any vertex pair $(x,y)$, $w: x \to y$. Let $S = N(y) \implies |S|= k$ where $N(y)$ denotes the neighborhood.

What can I say about the connectivity of $S$? I want to show that $(x,S)$ is a fan with $k$ distinct paths, but i'm not sure how to do that. Menger's theorem is relevant, but I haven't see how to apply it well.

Maybe I am not understanding the definition of a fan correctly. A $(x,S)$-fan is a set of disjoint paths whose only common vertex is $x$. So I need to show that a vertex cut of $x$ implies $F=\{x\}$ is a $(u,v)$-disconnecting set where $u,v \in S$.

But I've just drawn a $4$-connected graph and don't really know what the fan is. Can someone point it out to me? [image] Cutting out $x$ from this graph does not make the set $U$ (I used $U$ instead of $S$ here) disconnected. So..my condition of $U$ being a $(x,U)$-fan is incorrect. How then do I show it is a fan?